# Imprimir nombre de usuario al momento de loguearse

Tags: php, html

necesito algo de ayuda, necesito que al momento que un usuario se loguee me imprima el nombre de usuario en la pagina de bienvenida, ya he intentado varias cosas pero aun no lo he logrado, aqui planto como lo tengo hasta ahora. de ante mano gracias.

```
<?php
 session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || $_SESSION["user_id"]==null){
print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido!\");window.location='logueo.php';
</script>";
}?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bienvenido</title>
  </head>
<?php 
 require_once ('conexion.php');
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $consulta =<<<SQL
 SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id = '$id'LIMIT 1
 SQL;
 $filas = mysql_query ($consulta);
 $columnas = mysql_fetch_assoc($filas);
?>
<body>
 <?php include "php/navbar.php"; ?>
 <div class="bo">
    <div>
        <center><h2>Bienvenido <?php echo $columnas['fullname'];?></h2></center><br><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style="position: relative;">COMENZAR</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: puedes compartir que codigo usaste para ligrarlo: igmar27@gmail.com es mi mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php 
 require_once ('conexion.php');
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $consulta =<<<SQL
 SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id = '$id'LIMIT 1
 SQL;
 $filas = mysql_query ($consulta);
 $columnas = mysql_fetch_assoc($filas);
?>
```

trata esto 
Recuperamos el id del usuario desde la `session` no desde el `GET`

```
<?php 
    $id = $_SESSION["user_id"];

    $consulta = 'SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id = $id';
    $controlconsulta = mysql_query($consulta);
    while ($rowuser= mysql_fetch_array($controlconsulta)) {
     $nombrecompleto = $rowuser['fullname'];
    }

echo $nombrecompleto;

?>
```

Comment: Me dan 2 errores y no veo como solucionarlos aun no manejo bien php

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C: on line 24

Notice: Undefined variable: nombrecompleto in C:\ on line 31

Comment: Trata de revisar tu conexion.

Comment: La conexion esta bien, no se q sera el error, bueno si algo q veo es q la variable $nombrecompleto no esta definida es lo unico q veo.

Comment: la impresion del nombre no hay problema que este por fuera de la llave de cierre cierto -->  "}"  ?

Comment: No hay Problema, revisa si la variable que pusiste en fullname es la correcta y si la session te trae algún valor

Comment: Ya me dio, lo que hice fue sobre el codigo que ya tenia cambie lo que dijiste de Recuperamos el id del usuario desde la session no desde el GET cambie esa sola linea y me ha funcionado muy bien gracias.

Comment: No hay problema, Cualquier cosa estamos para ayudarte

Comment: Puedes indicarme como lo solucionaste?